# Adding jQuery.animate() to a Knockout.js custom binding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm using SignalR and Knockout.js to show movement in my View when there's changes to the Model on the server.

I have a very simple ViewModel for my Entities (which are little red squares which will "move" across the screen when they "move" server-side):

```
function Entity(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = data.UID;
    self.left = ko.observable(data.Left);
    self.top = ko.observable(data.Top);
}
```

My Knockout templating for my HTML is as follows (worth noting that my CSS class entity assigns absolute positioning):

```
<!-- ko foreach: entities -->
    <div data-bind="attr: { id: 'ent' + id }, style: { top: (top() + 'px'), left: (left() + 'px')}" class="entity">
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

So as my Model on the server changes (in this case it's a Location property) I use SignalR's RPC functionality to update the relevant ViewModel for each individual Entity.  This works as expected with my CSS `left` and `top` automagically updating as per the changes in the ViewModel, but I want it to look nice and smooth.

Searching online and SO for jQuery animations bound to a ViewModel using Knockout only really turns up fadeIn / fadeOut visibility animations, whereas I'm wanting to show "movement" across a canvas essentially.  Anyone had any success in doing something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change entity to

```
function Entity(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = data.UID;
    self.position = ko.observable({left: data.Left, top : data.Top});
}
```

and use this custom binding

```
ko.bindingHandlers.animate = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
       $(element).animate(valueAccessor(), 1000);
   }
};
```

view

```
<div data-bind="attr: { id: 'ent' + id }, animate: position()" class="entity">
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HjYr4/)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than directly setting the top and left positions through built in knockout bindings you can create your own custom binding.

Your html would look like:

```
<!-- ko foreach: entities -->
  <div data-bind="attr: {id: 'ent' + id }, moveable: { top: top(), left: left()">
  </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Then for your custom binding (named moveable in the above example) you can write add a jQuery transition to the binding's update function. It shoud look roughly like this:

```
update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var values = valueAccessor();
    $(element).animate({top: values.top() + 'px', left: values.left() + 'px'}, 1);
}
```

Later you can add more fancy options and logic to the custom binding to suit your needs. See: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html for more information on custom bindings.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions above are right, but they are too complicated.

I wrote much simplier example for your task - it changes the 'opacity' css property of a given element. You can check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/HjYr4/11/

```
ko.bindingHandlers.animateOpacity = {
update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    $(element).stop(true, false);
    $(element).animate({ opacity: valueAccessor() } , 1000);
}
```

Also you may find usefull to read the documentation about custom bindings here http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html (in my example animateOpactiy is a custom binding).

Good luck!